# Trouble getting blackberry json parsing code sample to work

Tags: java, eclipse, json, blackberry

I'm working on the Blackberry Eclipse plugin but can't get this sample to work :
[Code sample: Parsing a JSON data structure](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Code_sample_Parse_JSON_data_structure_1319797_11.jsp)

It doesn't go anywhere after `response = bsd.sendReceive();` 
The Simulator has internet access in the browser, and I also checked the "Launch Mobile Data System Connection Service (MDS-CS) with simulator." (odd that nothing shows up in fiddler, but hey)

The URI does seem to timeout quite often so I changed it to point to a file in my dropbox, but that didn't change anything.

Anyone have any success running this sample ?

Comment: are you seeing the MDS-CS console window stay open?  I've been having a problem recently with one of my plugins, where I checked the MDS-CS box, but it was always failing to launch ... so, just checking.

Comment: not seeing the MDS-CS console at all actually... but adding ";deviceside=true" works just fine...

Comment: if you use `;deviceside=true`, I think you're just using the **Direct TCP** transport, and sidestepping the MDS altogether.  [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11069129/119114) for some sample code that generates connection strings.  by the way, you can **Accept** your own answer if you've solved it ... that way, people know you don't still need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added ";deviceside=true" to uri