# issue with Http Connection in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am developing one application in which i need to pass parameter through POST method so i have try to implement with `HTTPConnection` but it getting me error. the are no establish connection.in this code i have pass parameter with `URLEncodedPostData` but it cant

here is my code ::

```
URLEncodedPostData postData = new URLEncodedPostData(URLEncodedPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, false);
                    //passing q’s value and ie’s value
                    postData.append("q", "remoQte");
                    postData.append("ie", "UTF-8");

                    ConnectionFactory conFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
                    ConnectionDescriptor conDesc = null;
                    try{
                        conDesc = conFactory.getConnection("http://www.google.co.in/search");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e.toString()+":"+e.getMessage());
                    }
                    String response = ""; // this variable used for the server response
                    // if we can get the connection descriptor from ConnectionFactory
                    if(null != conDesc){
                        try{
                            HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)conDesc.getConnection();
                            //set the header property
                            connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
                            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.size())); //body content of post data
                            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); // close the connection after success sending request and receiving response from the server
                            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // we set the content of this request as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, because the post data is encoded as form-urlencoded(if you print the post data string, it will be like this -> q=remoQte&ie=UTF-8).

                            //now it is time to write the post data into OutputStream
                            OutputStream out = connection.openOutputStream();
                            out.write(postData.getBytes());
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();

                            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); //when this code is called, the post data request will be send to server, and after that we can read the response from the server if the response code is 200 (HTTP OK).
                            if(responseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){
                                //read the response from the server, if the response is ascii character, you can use this following code, otherwise, you must use array of byte instead of String
                                InputStream in = connection.openInputStream();
                                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                                int read = -1;
                                while((read = in.read())!= -1)
                                    buf.append((char)read);
                                response = buf.toString();
                            }
                            Dialog.alert("response"+  response);

                            //don’t forget to close the connection
                            connection.close();

                        }catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println(e.toString()+":"+e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
```

**Update::**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

public class UiMainscreen extends MainScreen {
    ButtonField loginButton;
     private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
     private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
     private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
     private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
     private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
     private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
     private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
     private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
     private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
     private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";
    public UiMainscreen() {


        final ButtonField b=new ButtonField("JSON");
        add(b);

        FieldChangeListener listener=new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                if(field==b){

                    try{    
                    String URL = "http://www.google.co.in/";
                    String METHOD_NAME = "search";
                    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
                    String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;

                   SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;
                   HttpConnection httpConn = null;
                   HttpTransport httpt;
                   SoapPrimitive response = null;
                   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                   request.addProperty("q", "remoQte");
                   request.addProperty("ie", "UTF-8");
                   System.out.println("The request is=======" + request.toString());
                   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                   envelope.dotNet = true;
                   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                   httpt = new HttpTransport(URL);
                   httpt.debug = true;
                   try
                   {
                       httpt.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                       response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                       String result =  response.toString();
                       resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
}
                   catch (IOException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       System.out.println("The exception is IO==" + e.getMessage());
                   } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       System.out.println("The exception xml parser example==="
                               + e.getMessage());
                   }
                   System.out.println( resultRequestSOAP);
                   Dialog.alert("resultRequestSOAP"+resultRequestSOAP);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                         System.out.println("Problem==="
                                   + e.getMessage());
                    }
            }}
        };
        b.setChangeListener(listener);



    }
```

Comment: Which line? Paste your stacktrace please

Comment: can you please try it to in your eclipse

Comment: I think this is duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770789/unable-to-connect-to-internet-in-blackberry-device/11772234#11772234

Comment: You dint Add any Connection parameter to determine in which network you are requesting http Request. Have a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670246/httpconnection-connect-with-mobile-network-or-3g/11724735#11724735

Comment: can you please give answer according to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to post some parameters to in your connection, perhaps the following might help.

```
String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/xxx.asmx";
String METHOD_NAME = yourMethodName;
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;
SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;
HttpConnection httpConn = null;
HttpTransport httpt;
SoapPrimitive response = null;
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("username", user_id);
request.addProperty("password", password);
System.out.println("The request is=======" + request.toString());
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
httpt = new HttpTransport(URL+C0NNECTION_EXTENSION);
httpt.debug = true;
try
{
    httpt.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    String result =  response.toString();
    resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    System.out.println("The exception is IO==" + e.getMessage());
} 
catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
{
    System.out.println("The exception xml parser example==="
    + e.getMessage());
}
System.out.println( resultRequestSOAP);
return response + "";
```

This is passing two parameters to the webservice; username and password. you can modify accordingly. The Connection Extention is the part where you specify the kind of connection; BES,WIFI etc. Incase of the simulator you can add it as `connectionString = ";deviceside=true"`. This makes use of the Ksoap2 library that you can add in your project via **Properties -> Java Build Path -> Library**.

Comment: i have added library but what about `HttpTransport` class in blackberry its not derived

Comment: You use the HttpTransport of the Ksoap library. When you include the library (jar file) in your project, you can import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;

Comment: can you give me link frome where i can download HttpTransport jar file

Comment: @user1381267: [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/files/ksoap2/2.1.2/) you go! :)

Comment: @Sarah i got problem with library , it is attach with project but it not getting find the Ksoap Library. so can you please focus on this

Comment: Once you add the library via Properties -> Java Build Path -> Library tab -> Add external jar, you need to include it by clicking the Order and Export tab and then click the ksoap jar file you added.

Answer (score 1):

"No established connection" means that device can't connect to server with selected transport.  Please review this answer: [Unable to connect to internet in Blackberry device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770789/unable-to-connect-to-internet-in-blackberry-device/11772234#11772234)

After connection is established Sarah's post about passing parameters and data exchange should be helpful.